# Open Web Analytics with Node.JS web applicaiton. Getting Error 'TypeError: doc is null'

Tags: javascript, open-source, analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

**Scenario**: For a running web applications running on [Node.js](http://nodejs.org), we are integrating the [OpenWebAnalytics](http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com/index.php?title=Installation).

**Issue**: In firebug it shows the error as follows

```
TypeError: doc is null
[Break On This Error]   

...dth?window.innerWidth:document.body.offsetWidth;viewport.height=window.innerHeig...
```

At the line no **168** in the file named **owa.tracker.combined.min.js**

Method source code:

```
 getIframeDocument: function (iframe) {
        var doc = null;
        if (iframe.contentDocument) {
            doc = iframe.contentDocument;
        } else if (iframe.contentWindow && iframe.contentWindow.document) {
            doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        } else if (iframe.document) {
            doc = iframe.document;
        }
        if (doc == null) {
            OWA.debug("Document not found, append the parent element to the DOM before creating the IFrame");
        }
        doc.open();  // TypeError: doc is null
        doc.close();
        return doc;
    }
```

**Question**: Can anyone know the solution for this kind of issues?

Advance Thanks for great help

Comment: Are you trying to run a client-side script on Node.js? [OWA requires PHP 5.2.x or later](http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com/index.php?title=Technical_Requirements) suggests it only supports PHP on the server side.

Comment: No, its client script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ran into the same issue while configuring open web analytics in my application. Problem may be baseUrl which your are mentioned in the javascript snippet

Eg: Incorrect `var owa_baseUrl = 'http://yourdomain/path/to/owa';`

correct: `var owa_baseUrl = 'http://yourdomain/path/to/owa/';`

[Double check the javascript snippet embedded in the html file.](http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com/index.php?title=Tracker)